# Enviar push firebase con Could Function

Tags: nodejs, firebase, push-notification

estoy intentando crear una funcion en google could functions, para que cuando esta es llamada desde una app, envie una notificacion a otra app. ( le quiero avisar al propietario de una tienda que le realizaron una compra )
Tengo el id de firebase para enviar la notificacion y quero usar could function para simplificar todo.

agrego la funcion add mensaje como para probar y inserto el codigo que esta en el ejemplo de firebase, pero me tira el siguiente error:

Error: could not handle the request

Mi codigo es:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => 
{
    var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
    var request = require('request');
    var serviceAccount = require("service_account.json");
    firebase.initializeApp({
        credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
    });
    const registrationTokens = ['cRBGLX6vTMuXJw8v7615wz:APA91bF1O1_wzsqG9sse-SivFepProqzGqDxDI2-43vsqz-XQPgMgNvckcUaTloveTAAOE0j1u4jy75wrwMKkOJ2j3j-_9C1cIgk3xKPWkXWe6LASOxJ36VIDZwvjFXc-VIwxYyQuW5E'];
    const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'You have a new follower!',
          body: 'xzczxc'
        }
      };
    const response = await firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload);
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: zxc added.`});
});
```

No se me ocurre en que me equivoco.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu función solamente da una respuesta si el envío fue exitoso. Debes hacer el envío dentro de un `try catch` y enviar una respuesta en ambos bloques. Además el método `sendToDevice()` es legacy. En su lugar deberías usar `send()` o `sendMulticast()`.

Quedaría mas o menos así:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'You have a new follower!',
            body: 'xzczxc'
        },
        token: 'cRBGLX6vTMuXJw8v7615wz:APA91bF1O1_wzsqG9sse-SivFepProqzGqDxDI2-43vsqz-XQPgMgNvckcUaTloveTAAOE0j1u4jy75wrwMKkOJ2j3j-_9C1cIgk3xKPWkXWe6LASOxJ36VIDZwvjFXc-VIwxYyQuW5E'
    };
    try {
        const messageId = await admin.messaging().send(message)
        res.json({ result: `Message with ID:${messageId} added.` });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ result: `Error ${e.code}: ${e.message}` });
    }
});
```

En la documentación de Firebase hay una [lista de códigos de error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin) con sus respectivas descripciones. Si muestras cual es tu error, puedo tratar de ayudarte a solucionarlo.